# Adjoints of an operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

In a paper I'm reading the discussion centres on operators of the form

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B} = (-1)^{m+1} \Delta^m_y + \frac{1}{2m}y\cdot\nabla_y
\end{equation}

Apparently this is symmetric for $m=1$ and is not symmetric for $m\geq 2$, and does not admit self-adjoint extension.

Two things - I have been trying, probably naively, to integrate by parts against a test function to see why the symmetry property doesn't hold in higher dimensions, and haven't been getting anywhere. I'm not really sure how to deal with the second term. Could anyone clear this up for me please?

Secondly, what exactly is meant by a self-adjoint extension? I get that it's to do with being defined on the whole space, but I'm not really clear what this actually means. I get that this isn't a very clear question, but I don't really understand enough yet to frame it any better.

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you please define the spaces that you are working with. Also, could you say what is the paper you are reading (sometimes there are crucial informations on the paper). Thank you

Comment: Thanks Tomas. The paper is  http://epubs.siam.org/sam-bin/doi/abs/10.1137/S003613990241552X,  the relevant material starts on pp 1779. What I call $\bf B$ is $\bf{\mathcal L}^*$. I'm not completely clear on spaces, as this operator is one derived from a self-similar solution to the original operator acting on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}_+$. I think that means $\bf B$ acts on that space as well, right?